# Drive Mapping with Azure Scale Sets using Desired State Configuration

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, dsc

I am running into an interesting issue. Maybe you fine folks can help me understand what's happening here. If there's a better method, I'm all ears.

I am running a DSC Configuration on Azure and would like to map a drive. I've read this really isn't what DSC is for, but I am not aware of any other way of doing this outside of DSC with Azure Scalesets. Here's the portion of the script I am running into issues:

```
Script MappedDrive
    {
        SetScript = 
        {
        $pass = "passwordhere" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -force
        $user = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "username",$pass
        New-PSDrive -Name W -PSProvider FileSystem -root \\azurestorage.file.core.windows.net\storage -Credential $user -Persist
        }
        TestScript = 
        {
            Test-Path -path "W:"
        }
        GetScript = 
        {
        $hashresults = @{}
        $hashresults['Exists'] = test-path W:
        }
    }
```

I've also attempted this code in the SetScript section:

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive('W:','\\azurestorage.file.core.windows.net\storage',$true,'username','passwordhere')
```

I've also tried a simple net use command to map the drive instead of the fancy, New-Object or New-PSDrive cmdlets. Same behavior.

If I run these commands (New-Object/Net Use/New-PSDrive) **manually**, the machine will map the drive if I run it with a separate drive letter. Somehow, the drive is attempting to be mapped but isn't mapping.

Troubleshooting I've done:

- There is no domain in my environment. I am simply attempting to create a scale set and run DSC to configure the machine using the storage account credentials granted upon creation of the storage account.
- I am using the username and password that is given to me by the Storage Account user id and access key (randomly generated key, with usually the name of the storage account as the user).
- Azure throws no errors on running the DSC module (No errors in Event Log, Information Only - Resource execution sequence properly lists all of my sequences in the DSC file.)
- When I log into the machine and check to see if the drive is mapped, I run into a disconnected network drive on the drive letter I want (W:).
- If I open Powershell, I receive an error: "Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'FileSystem' provider failed."
- If I run "Get-PSDrive" the W: drive does not appear.
- If I run the SetScript code manually inside a Powershell Console,  the mapped drive works fine under a different drive letter.
- If I try to disconnect the W: drive, I receive "This network connection does not exist."
- I thought maybe DSC needed some time before mapping and added a Sleep Timer, but that didn't work. Same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem before, while it didn't involve DSC, mounting an Azure File share would be fine until the server would be restarted, then it would appear as a disconnected drive. This happend if i used New-Object/Net Use/New-PSDrive with the persist option.

The answer to that issue, i found in the [updated docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files)

> Persist your storage account credentials for the virtual machine
>
> Before mounting to the file share, first persist your storage account
>   credentials on the virtual machine. This step allows Windows to
>   automatically reconnect to the file share when the virtual machine
>   reboots. To persist your account credentials, run the cmdkey command
>   from the PowerShell window on the virtual machine. Replace
>    with the name of your storage account, and
>    with your storage account key.

`cmdkey /add:<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net /user:<storage-account-name> /pass:<storage-account-key>`

> Windows will now reconnect to your file share when the virtual machine
>   reboots. You can verify that the share has been reconnected by running
>   the net use command from a PowerShell window.
>
> Note that credentials are persisted only in the context in which
>   cmdkey runs. If you are developing an application that runs as a
>   service, you will need to persist your credentials in that context as
>   well.
>
> Mount the file share using the persisted credentials
>
> Once you have a remote connection to the virtual machine, you can run
>   the net use command to mount the file share, using the following
>   syntax. Replace  with the name of your storage
>   account, and  with the name of your File storage share.

`net use <drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name>
example :
net use z: \\samples.file.core.windows.net\logs`

> Since you persisted your storage account credentials in the previous
>   step, you do not need to provide them with the net use command. If you
>   have not already persisted your credentials, then include them as a
>   parameter passed to the net use command, as shown in the following
>   example.

Edit:
I don't have an Azure VM free to test it on, but this works fine on a Server 2016 hyper-v vm

```
Script MapAzureShare
    {
        GetScript = 
        {

        }
        TestScript = 
        {
            Test-Path W:
        }
        SetScript = 
        {
            Invoke-Expression -Command "cmdkey /add:somestorage.file.core.windows.net /user:somestorage /pass:somekey"
            Invoke-Expression -Command "net use W: \\somestorage.file.core.windows.net\someshare"
        }
        PsDscRunAsCredential = $credential
    }
```

In my brief testing the drive would only appear after the server was rebooted.

Comment: This actually ends up throwing an error for me.

            [[Script]MappedDrive] Performing the operation "Set-TargetResource" on 
target "Executing the SetScript with the user supplied credential".
VERBOSE: [2016-12-09T14:51:06] [ERROR] System error 1312 has occurred.
VERBOSE: [2016-12-09T14:51:06] [ERROR] 

A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Comment: Did you use the `PsDscRunAsCredential`? `cmdkey` won't work without it.

Comment: 'PsDscRunAsCredential' is not valid. If i use Credtial instead the cmdkey never gets the user I pass results. I'm afraid this is not possible as in https://powershell.org/forums/topic/remotely-setting-network-credentials-using-cmdkey/

Answer (score 0):

What I imagine is happening here:
DSC runs under the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account and unless the Credential attribute has been set, the `Computer account` is used when pulling the files from a network share. But looking at how Azure Files operate, permissions shouldn't be an issue, but running this whole process under `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` could. I suggest you try to [run DSC as a user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/runasuser) of your VM's and see if that works.

ps. You could also try to perform the same operation against a VM with network share where you are confident that share\ntfs permissions are correct. You might need to enable [anonymous user to access your share](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cad57344-0d3d-433f-b3f8-df6187ddbbf4/accessing-domain-shared-folder-from-nondomain-computer?forum=w7itpronetworking) for that to work.

Comment: Remember that this is not a standard share. This share is built out using Azure Shared File Storage. A share is created using the Azure Portal and / or using Powershell cmdlets. You don't modify user permissions like normal shares on a Windows server.

Comment: I've never said anywhere in my answer to modify any permission, please, read before commenting. @227Passive